# None of the virtual devices in android studio offer api 31, how can i run my code if i selected the api as >=31?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-api-levels, android-api-31

I selected the API for my android studio app to be 31 or higher to be able to use the jetpack plug-ins, but none of the virtual device configuration phones have this API, so I can't run my code. How can I go around this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What is the version of your android studio? Probably updating to the latest version may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it not showing on your device, But on my device Manager, it properly shows up to 32, and `Tiramisu`. See the below image. First, try to `Refresh`, [image] if more `API 31,32 not show` then follow my second step.
[image: this is my device manager]

---

2nd - If you do not find your API level in the `Recommended` area, Just click on `Other Images` as below image

[image: other Images]

You can see all of an `API levels` here. If problem not solved yet, let me know

Comment: this worked, it was under "other images". thank you!!

Comment: @SomeoneLearning17 you're welcome